# HTML Form using Javascript did not verify instead changed the link

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Code:

```
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form onsubmit="loginUsingPassword(this.form.loginPassword.value);return false;">
Password : <input type="password" name="loginPassword" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
//This is for verifying use.
function generateUserPassword(){
var passwordArray = [];
passwordArray[0]="198237645";
passwordArray[1]="infotalkong";
function loginUsingPassword(inputPassword){
for (int i; i<passwordArray.length; i++){
if (inputPassword=passwordArray[i]){
document.cookie="reportLogged=true;";
window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com/report.html";
}
}
}
</script>
```

Result:

Input : 198237645
Output : The link changed to http://tool-box.weebly.com/report-login.html?loginPassword=198237645

What is the solution?

Comment: `if (inputPassword=passwordArray[i]){
document.cookie="reportLogged=true;";
window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com/report.html";
}else{return false;}` try this

Comment: if `==` problem. i've figure this out.

Comment: `if (inputPassword=passwordArray[i]){` It should be `if (inputPassword==passwordArray[i]){` == not =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure of your requirement, but there are some points might be helpful for you,

- Generally we use method post for such form submission, rather than the default one(get).

So you might want to to change the follow code

```
<form onsubmit="loginUsingPassword(this.form.loginPassword.value);return false;">
```

to the follow one

```
<form onsubmit="loginUsingPassword(this.form.loginPassword.value);return false;" method="post">
```

After you do the above change, the password will not be displayed in the URL as you mentioned, to avoid security issue.

- By reading your code, I assume you would like to check whether the password inputed by user is the same as a list of predefined password in your code.

But you have the follow code there

```
if (inputPassword=passwordArray[i]){//This is a common bug to mistake === to = in if
```

If you would like to compare the variable *inputPassword* and your predefined passwords(*passwordArray*), you should use == or === rather than the assignment operation(=), so the code should be

```
if (inputPassword === passwordArray[i]){
```

Hope the above hints could help you on debug your code.

Here is a working version based on my understanding to your requirement, but actually you didn't specify your requirement...

```
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form onsubmit="loginUsingPassword(document.forms['myForm']['loginPassword'].value);return false;" method="post" name="myForm">
Password : <input type="password" name="loginPassword" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    //This is for verifying use.
    var passwordArray = [];
function generateUserPassword(){
    passwordArray[0]="198237645";
    passwordArray[1]="infotalkong";
}

function loginUsingPassword(inputPassword) {
    generateUserPassword();
    var passwordCorrect = false;
    for (i = 0; i< passwordArray.length; i++){
        if (inputPassword === passwordArray[i]){
            document.cookie="reportLogged=true;";
            passwordCorrect = true;
            window.location.href="http://tool-box.weebly.com/report.html";
        }
    }
    if (passwordCorrect !== true){
        alert("Wrong Password!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6YapV/       This is the code that i changed, but not working. What shall i do?

Comment: You should return false if the validation didn't pass, I will post the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tag has no `method` attribute, so it defaults to `GET`. It has no `action` attribute, so it defaults to the page you're on. If you submit the form, it encodes the submitted values in the URL (how GET is designed to work) and you land on the same page. This is exactly the behavior you have specified.

Comment: How can you change it _to do what_?

Comment: sorry. do i need to change it to POST?

Comment: Well, for one thing, if you change it to `POST`, the passed arguments will no longer be visibly encoded in the URL. You're not specifying what you want it to do, so it's hard to suggest a way to do it.